# Using third-party email with Kentico 8

Tags: email, kentico

I'm trying to use SendGrid (or MailGun) and not use the SMTP settings but through an API.

Where in Kentico would I set this up?  Would I change the `CMSModules_EmailQueue_SendEmail.SendEmail()` method?

Answer (score 2):

To handle emails from the whole system you need to customize the EmailProvider.
See this section in the documenttation on how to do it.
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Custom+Email+provider+example

In general the methods(`SendEmailInternal`, `SendEmailAsyncInternal`) will still have the signature with `SMTPServerInfo`, but you will not use it in any way and instead of it you'll implement you custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

If by now you have upgraded to one of the latest Kentico versions then you might find helpful my SendGridEmailProvider class implementing the integration with [SendGrid API version 3](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html) on GitHub [here](https://github.com/kate-orlova/sendgrid-email-provider-for-kentico)